# Problem with Mapserver label encoding in Greek

Tags: labeling, mapserver, encoding, internationalization

I'm having a problem when trying to render a shapefile's labels that has Greek characters with the use of truetype and I'm getting weird characters. The code for my label section is as follows:

`LABEL
                   TYPE truetype
                   FONT arial
                   SIZE 12
                   COLOR 50 50 50
                   PARTIALS FALSE
                   ENCODING ISO-8859-7
               END`

I've also tried to use ENCODING GREEK  or even WINDOWS-1253 and UTF-8. But always getting weird letters.

Comment: Are you sure your Arial variant has the glyphs?

Comment: Yes. The alias is arial and the glyph is "Vera.ttf". fonts.list file and glyphs are in the same folder.  The FONTSET in my mapfile is set to: FONTSET "/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/mapserver-fonts/fonts.list"

Comment: If the font is ok, my guess would be the data was corrupted (pe. saved with a different encoding without conversion). Did you get just the shape file or also accompanying files (one contains the charset)?

Comment: Which one contains the charset?  I think my files are OK (the folder contains: .dbf, .prj, .sbn, sbx, shp, shp.xml and .shx). I experimented by making my own shapefiles and saving them with different encoding. Specifically I tried ISO-8859-7 and WINDOWS-1253. I also tried "greek" encoding but it was saving the shapefile with encoding ISO-8859-7 which I had already tried.

Comment: Could you make a small zipped shapefile with just a few features for testing?

Comment: Well... I created a shapefile that has only two fields, ID and road for example and only two records: ID:1 and road:<some greek letters>. Didn't work either

Comment: I meant that you would share the sample data so that others could make some tests with it. I suppose you run MapServer on Windows.

Comment: You mean upload them here somehow ???  No I'm using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon.

Comment: The .cpg file contains the charset, but you don't have it. So yes, something to play with would be best.